# How to resolve the "Error creating bean with name 'step2' defined in class path resource " exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, noclassdeffounderror, spring-retry

Below `step2()` method of my sample spring batch project works fine in one PC and throws the below error in another PC.

Can someone please explain  what's wrong with my code?

> ```
> Error: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'step2' defined in class path resource
> [com/xxxx/yyy/configuration/CustomJobConfiguration.class]: Bean
> instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Step]: Factory method
> 'step2' threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/springframework/classify/Classifier
> ```

Method:

```
@Bean
public Step step2() {
    System.out.println("Entering step2()");

    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step2")
            .<String, String>chunk(Integer.valueOf(chunkSize))
            .faultTolerant()
            .reader(reader())
            .writer(writer())
            .build();
}
```

Comment: Just check if you have org.springframework.classify.Classifier.jar in your classpath

Comment: Do you use a dependency management tool like maven or gradle? If so, then you need to import `spring-batch-infrastructure` in your project which will bring `spring-retry` dependency and solve your issue. Otherwise, you need to make sure your have `spring-retry` in your classpath.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I do have spring-batch-infrastructure jar in my class path. The weird part is it works on one machine and it throws the above exception on another.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing [spring-retry](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.retry/spring-retry) dependency jar for [Classifier](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.retry/spring-retry) class

> Spring Retry provides an abstraction around retrying failed operations